# Categorical encoder missing out levels

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, scikit-learn

```
import category_encoders as ce
ord_Ce = ce.ordinal.OrdinalEncoder()
ord_Ce.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame([2, np.nan, 3]).astype(object))
```

produces `2->1, np.nan->0, 3->3` encoding. Why is it missing out on 2 while encoding. It would seem to me that 3 should be encoded as 2 by the encoder. Any light on why this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Skimming through the [source code](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/_modules/category_encoders/ordinal.html#OrdinalEncoder) reveals that in the `ordinal_encoding`-function, the numbers of categories are enumerated  (3 categories in total, starting from 1) and these figures are also used for the encoding

```
categories_dict = {x: i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(categories)}
X[str(col) + '_tmp'] = X[col].map(lambda x: categories_dict.get(x))
```

afterwards missing values are imputed to 0.

Summarizing: np.nan has the category 2 which is transformed to 0 in a post processing step